# AngularJS: how to update a ng-repeat on new data form a db source

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an `ng-repeat` on my page below:

```
  <div class="store-listing-wrapper" ng-repeat="store in stores | filter:storesearch" ng-cloak>
    <div class="store-listing" style="background: url('storeassets/[[ store.folder ]]/Stores_Poster.jpg') center no-repeat;">
        <a class="title" href="store/[[ store.id ]]">[[ store.name ]] <span class="typcn typcn-chevron-right"></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
{{-- Preloader --}}
<div class="content-preloader" ng-hide="stores.length > 0"></div>
```

This is linked to my `storelistingCtrl` which uses a factory to retrieve a list of stores from a database.

```
  .controller('storelistingCtrl',function($scope, Store, $state, $log){
       //-- init the stores list to display
       $scope.getStoreList();
       //-- set listen for a new store adddition then regenerate data
       $scope.$on('newStore', function(e) { $scope.getStoreList();});
       //-- get the store data
       $scope.getStoreList = function(){
            Store.getStores().then(
                 function(stores){$scope.stores = stores; },
                 function(statusCode){debug(statusCode)}
            );
       };
    })
```

Everything is ok and works.

But on this page I have a popup/modal form that is used to create a new store.  Once this has been completed, I close the popup/modal.

I then currently use a `$broadcast` to the `storelistingCtrl` to let the app know that the db has new data and to then call the `$scope.getStoreList` to then repopulate the ng-repeat/ store list on the html page.

This `$broadcast` is located in my `createStoreCtrl` below:

```
.controller('createStoreCtrl',function($scope, $state, $log, Store, $http, $rootScope){
   $scope.submitForm = function(store){
    Store.addStore(store).then(
       function(res){
          if(res == 'true'){...
           $rootScope.$broadcast("newStore", "");
           ....
```

Once the popup/modal closes the event is fired and the store listings page is reloaded with the new data.

My problem is this seems to have been too easy and was wondering if this is a good approach or not and is there a better way to execute the same thing but cleaner

Comment: Personally I don't like the getters/settters and broadcasting event and would prefer to write it to use two-way data binding but it isn't an antipattern if that's what are you asking for

Comment: in a way its cause i'm newish to angular especially taking it to this level etc, so its the only way i know how but could at least take a peak at two-way data binding process.. thanks

Comment: Here is a very good article on angularjs antipaterns and pitfalls, i think someone new can really get use it http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/19/5-angularjs-antipatterns-and-pitfalls/

Comment: @maurycy thanks will have a look

Answer (score 0):

The joy of angularJS is there are many ways of achieving this, but your way certainly isn't wrong, and as you found it's very easy to implement.

Some people frown upon using $broadcast and $emit because they view it as kinda of `jump to` statements in other languages which is understandable. Sometimes it just makes sense to use them

The way you've done it works well. Another way you could do it would be to have the service have a new method which the modal calls to trigger a refresh, which then broadcasts that it is finished with the new data, so your controller wouldn't have to call the update itself. You can then store that data in the service so that it is accessible to other controllers if needed.

At the end of the day though, there's no wrong way. It may be worth looking through angularJS's own code, and documentation and google groups to see how they recommend handling this kind of thing, but it really is preferential.

I often make use of the $broadcasts, as I try and avoid using `$watch` due to the performance penalty (one or two don't hurt but hundreds can start slowing things down) but that's just a personal choice.

Whatever makes the code readable, and better yet reusable, is a good way to go

Comment: Thanks for the reply agree but that can be the trouble of many ways, which i fell into is 'Is this correct..' perhaps finding my comfort point and using it.  I agree about doing that function call all within the factory thus keeping say the Store stuff in one. Might have a look into moving that into the Store factory, thanks

Comment: `$broadcast` weren't good either, it's only from version 1.2.6 or 1.2.8 where `$broadcast` got improved and it goes only to scopes with listeners - previously it was going from top (if called on rootScope) to the last child scope - far worse than watch ;)

Comment: @maurycy ah didn't realise it was broken before. Least they've fixed it. My biggest issue with watches is when it comes to `ng-repeat`. Then `bindonce` is a life saver :)

Comment: I don't want to create chat here so that's my last message, you can check ng-repeat and `track by` option now, it's a life saver if you update big objects, if you feel chatty catch me on #angularjs irc channel `maurycyg`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need events to share information about new elements added to array.

Consider how data are shared between service and factory:

**View**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myApp">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in getElements()">
        {{ item }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller & Factory**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myApp', function($scope, list) {    
  $scope.getElements = function() {
    return list.elements;
  };
}).factory('list', function($interval) {
  var elements = [];
  var elementsAdded = 0;
  var interval = $interval(function() {
    ++elementsAdded;
    elements.push(elementsAdded);

    if(elementsAdded >= 5) {
        $interval.cancel(interval);
    }        
  }, 500);

  return {
    elements: elements
  };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/krzysztof_safjanowski/ybzLs/

Comment: i know  about the push method but the dat comes form a DB and on inital load thats fine i can populate the list but what about when new data is added, the data in the form is not all thats is added, more is added in the background so i cannot simply then do a push to the list, as well as add the data, it would need to be called form the DB. thanks

Comment: push method is not the clue of this method. Angular internally watches to changes in deep objects. You should have service that is responsible for data fetching and adding. You know when data is added - so, call the method from service to refresh list, or add this new added data to elements list.
Initial load should be done in when routes are resolved in app.js (or similar) file.